# Why is not working the link from an html in a textview?

Tags: android, html, kotlin, textview

I'm getting an html from a service that I need to print in a textview. In this case the html has two links the first one works bt the second one doesn't.

XML:

```
<TextView
                        android:id="@+id/_doctor_comments"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:paddingStart="16dp"
                        android:paddingTop="12dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                        android:textSize="14dp"
                        app:textType="regular"/>
```

Print code in textview:

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            val result = Html.fromHtml(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(data.consultationData.doctorAnswer, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY).toString())
            txtDoctorComments.text = result
            txtDoctorComments.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
        } else {
            txtDoctorComments.text = Html.fromHtml(Html.fromHtml(data.consultationData.doctorAnswer).toString())
            txtDoctorComments.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
        }
```

This is what I get from the service:

```
Esto es lo que debes hacer &lt;a href=&quot;https://www.google.com&quot;&gt;link aqui&lt;/a&gt;

esto es otra prueba solo con el texto https://www.google.com
```

And here you can see what it's print in the textview:

[image]

And as you can see the htts://www.google.com will not behave as a link and it isn't highlighted and neither clickable. If anyone has a clue of why this happens please give me any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are two things.

1. Your other link is just added as plain text. It does not have a `<a href` which can be detected by `HtmlCompat.fromHtml`. So if you want that second text is also displayed as a link. You've to modify the response.

**Example:**

```
val sampleText =
            "Esto es lo que debes hacer &lt;a href=&quot;https://www.google.com&quot;&gt;link aqui&lt;/a&gt;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "esto es otra prueba solo con el texto &lt;a href=&quot;https://www.google.com&quot;&gt;https://www.google.com&lt;/a&gt;"

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            val result = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(
                HtmlCompat.fromHtml(
                    sampleText,
                    HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY
                ).toString(), HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY
            )
            txtDoctorComments.text = result
            txtDoctorComments.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
        } else {
            txtDoctorComments.text =
                Html.fromHtml(Html.fromHtml(sampleText).toString())
            txtDoctorComments.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
        }
```

**Output:**

[image: Device link 1]

2. If you want an automatic way to detect links from plain text which does not have anchor text then you can use `Linkify.addLinks(txtDoctorComments,Linkify.WEB_URLS)`.

**Example:**

```
val sampleText =
            "Esto es lo que debes hacer &lt;a href=&quot;https://www.google.com&quot;&gt;link aqui&lt;/a&gt;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "esto es otra prueba solo con el texto https://www.google.com"


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            val result = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(
                HtmlCompat.fromHtml(
                    sampleText,
                    HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY
                ).toString(), HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY
            )
            txtDoctorComments.text = result
            Linkify.addLinks(txtDoctorComments, Linkify.WEB_URLS)
        } else {
            txtDoctorComments.text =
                Html.fromHtml(Html.fromHtml(sampleText).toString())
            txtDoctorComments.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
        }
```

**Output:**

[image: device link 2]

**Note:** You can either have an anchor tag "<a" or a plain-text link. Unfortunately, both can't be combined directly.

Comment: now i understand why it doesn't work both link, but is there a way to show both links highlighted and clickable? Your second option is what I am looking for because the response from the server is always different in wich case there can be different urls, but the first link it doesn't seem to work from your second option as you state I can't combined them directly

Comment: @MarioMuresean Unfortunately One option overrides the other. There's no direct way(that I know of). Unless maybe you write your own `PatternMatcher` & link that.

Comment: I'm thinking to use a regex to find urls in plain text then use your first option and that can work